# Driving directions in new google maps

Tags: google-maps

I've just got a new phone and downloaded the new Google Maps. I cannot find the written driving directions in this version. There used to be a list of the directions that appeared together with white circles showing where you need to change directions on the map.

Is this still there? Where can I find this view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you get the directions for a route, you can pull the bottom white bar up to see the detailed, written instructions.

You can also drag the bottom white bar to the left to see more of the available routes.

Comment: pff that was not so obvious to find. Google should implement some ui hints I think. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Snuur - If you consider this answer correct, you should accept it by hitting the checkmark button next to it.